# Determine Typescript property type with reflection at runtime

Tags: typescript, reflection, typescript2.0

When transpiling TypeScript to JavaScript, my understanding is that TypeScript type information is lost and features like reflection will only work in a very limited manner. We're using JavaScript reflection at runtime, which understandably has limited "knowledge" about TypeScript types.

Could there be a way to retrieve TypeScript type information at runtime?

Let's take the following snippet, available on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/sparkbuzz/pen/ZKaZNx/):

```
class Book {
    public title: string;
    public isbn: string;
}

class Author {
    public name: string = '';
    public books: Book[] = [];

    constructor() {
        const r = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'books');

        console.log(`typeof: ${typeof this.books}`);
        console.log(`constructor: ${this.books.constructor.name}`);
        console.log(r);
    }
}

const author = new Author();
```

The logs output "object", "Array" and:

```
Object {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: [],
    writeable: true
}
```

I want to iterate over the properties of Author, and determine the type of *Author.books* or any property. I am expecting to be able to establish at runtime that, *Author.books* is an *Array of Books*. Simply knowing that it is an object or an array does not help with what I am trying to achieve at all.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to hazard an answer and say it cannot be done with what is available to you by default - you'd need to parse the `d.ts` to get true reflection of all the types.

As you say; the array is an instance of `Array`, the only way to infer what *type* the array is supposed to contain is to pass the class of the desired type. So, you *could* do something like this:

```
class Book {
  public title: string;
  public isbn: string;
}

type Newable<T> = {
  new (): T;
}

class Author<T> {
  public name: string = '';
  public books: T[] = [];

  constructor(bookRef: Newable<T>) {
    console.log(`name: ${bookRef.name}`);
  }
}

const author = new Author(Book);
```

Not amazing, and it only works if Book is a class.

typescript can also infer the type you use for Book from what you pass to the constructor:

[image]

`bookRef.name` will get you the class name at runtime.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. TypeScript doesn't have reified types, let alone reified generic types so your nicely explicit solution dispels any illusions of runtime type magic.

Comment: Pity that, would’ve really been handy to have type info in a project I’m working on currently.